# Xcode: running ASM

Tags: xcode, assembly

I have this ASM that I have been trying to run in Xcode without success:

```
_asm
{
    push eax
    push ebx
    push ecx
    mov eax,[A]
    mov ebx,[B]
    xor eax,ebx
    mov ecx,eax
    xor ecx,ebx
    mov ebx,ecx
    xor eax,ebx
    mov [A],eax 
    mov [B],ebx 
    pop eax 
    pop ebx 
    pop ecx 
}
```

I have tried changing it to `__asm__` but the error is still persistent:

> inline asm:6:2: Unknown use of instruction mnemonic without a size suffix

I have searched online for hours but none seems to answer my question.

I am running Xcode 5.0.2.

Does anyone know what I may need to set in Xcode in order to run this?

Comment: Sounds like the compiler is expecting `gas` syntax (where every instruction has a suffix showing its size, register names start with `%`, and the source and destination operands are reversed).  It'd look like `pushl %eax` `movl (A), %eax` etc, or something quite close to that.

Comment: You might be able to say `-Xassembler -msyntax=intel` to get it to recognize what you have.

Comment: It takes quite a bit more than that.  See http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/GAS_Syntax for more info.

Comment: When writing assembler for the x86, there are 2 common formats: intel format, and att format. There are a number of differences between these formats (such as the % that Unheilig mentioned).  Depending on your assembler, you can request it to use one format or the other.  The code you have posted looks like intel format.  The error message clearly indicates that it is compiling for att format.  You either need to tell your compiler to use intel format (as cHao was trying to suggest) or re-write the code in att format.  There are a number of references for both formats (check google).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The equivalent GCC-style asm statement would be:

```
__asm__(
    "push %%eax\n\t"
    "push %%ebx\n\t"
    "push %%ecx\n\t"
    "mov %0,%%eax\n\t"
    "mov %1,%%ebx\n\t"
    "xor %%ebx,%%eax\n\t"
    "mov %%eax,%%ecx\n\t"
    "xor %%ebx,%%ecx\n\t"
    "mov %%ecx,%%ebx\n\t"
    "xor %%ebx,%%eax\n\t"
    "mov %%eax,%0\n\t"
    "mov %%ebx,%0\n\t"
    "pop %%ecx\n\t"
    "pop %%ebx\n\t"
    "pop %%eax"
    : "+m" (A), "+m" (B));
```

(I've corrected an apparent bug by popping the saved values on the stack back into their original registers.)

I'm not sure what the point of this assembly statement is though. It goes to a lot of effort to do something that could be done much more efficiently in three lines of C/C++ code:

```
temp = A;
A = B;
B = temp;
```

If I were to pretend though that it did something useful, and not just swap two variables, then I would suggest getting rid of the apparently unimportant PUSH/POP instructions like this:

```
__asm__(
    "xor %1,%0\n\t"
    "mov %0,%2\n\t"
    "xor %1,%2\n\t"
    "mov %2,%1\n\t"
    "xor %1,%0"
    : "+r" (A), "+r" (B), "=r" (temp));
```

Comment: If the goal is to swap two values, how about just `asm ("" : "=r" (b), "=r" (a) : "0" (a), "1" (b));`?  Hard to beat 0 statements for performance...

Comment: Well, if the original poster's code is supposed to be a practical example my suggestion would be to use the C/C++ example code I gave.

Comment: True, that's probably best.